# How do I reset paragraph numbering only after new chapter?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I'm writing a report that needs some annoying formatting. The `\chapter`s and `\paragraph`s need to be numbered using arabic numbers.

The paragraph numbering needs to be reset at the commencement of each new chapter. The `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` headings should not be numbered, nor should they have any effect on the `\paragraph` numbering.

I can't figure out how to:

1. Reset the `\paragraph` numbering to 1 at the start of each `\chapter`.
2. Prevent the `\paragraph` numbering from being reset at the start of a new `\subsubsection`.

Bearing in mind I have used the `titlesec` package to change the appearance of my titles, what is the easiest way to achieve the desired outcome?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
%  Paragraph counter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amstext,amsmath,calc}
% Section headings
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\uppercase}
    {\bf{\thechapter.}}
    {1em}
    {\bfseries\filcenter}
    []
\titleformat{\section}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\uppercase}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\bfseries}
    []
\titleformat{\subsection}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\bfseries}
    []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {}
    [{\titleline*[l]{\titlerule}}]
\titleformat{\paragraph}
    [runin]
    {\normalfont}
    {\theparagraph.} 
    {1em}
    {}
    []
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
    {0pc}
    {11pt}
    {11pt}
    []
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\paragraph{}First paragraph, numbered 1.
\section{First Section}
\paragraph{}Second paragraph, numbered 2.
\subsection{First Subsection}
\paragraph{}Third paragraph, numbered 3.
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\paragraph{}Fourth paragraph, should be numbered 4.
\chapter{Second chapter, numbered 2.}
\paragraph{}This paragraph should be numbered 1.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `chngcntr` package is perfect for doing this sort of thing:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection} % removes paragraph from the subsubsections
\counterwithin{paragraph}{chapter} % makes paragraph depend on chapter
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}} % redefine the display of the paragraph
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I've been faffing around with new counters and all kinds of rubbish this evening. I knew it didn't have to be that hard!

Answer (score 4):

Alan Munn's solution can be improved by using the starred version `\counterwithin*` -- hereby, the `paragraph` counter will be made dependend on the `chapter` counter *without* changing the definition of `\theparagraph`.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}% makes paragraph independend from subsubsection;
%     redefines \theparagraph as \arabic{paragraph}
\counterwithin*{paragraph}{chapter}% makes paragraph depend on chapter;
%     does not change definition of \theparagraph
```